# How to sort array of dictionary when value is same?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I know how to sort array of nsdictionary by its key. But the issue for me occur, when the value of the key are the same, then how to sort between them say by another key?

For eg

```
[{
key1 = 2;
key2 = A;
},
{
key1 = 1;
key2 = D;
},
{
key1 = 1;
key2 = E;
},
{
key1 = 1;
key2 = C;
}]
```

When i sort by key1, then the 3 items will be at top, and key1=2 dictionary will be at bottom.

I want to sort the 3 items by key2 after the whole array has been sorted by key1. Basically my aim:

```
[{
key1 = 1;
key2 = C;
},
{
key1 = 1;
key2 = D;
},
{
key1 = 1;
key2 = E;
},
{
key1 = 2;
key2 = A;
}]
```

Here is my code to sort by key1:

```
sortedArr = [dataDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:
                     ^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary* obj1, NSDictionary* obj2)
                     {
                         NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedSame;
                         if(obj1["key1"] != nil && obj2["key1"]!=nil)
                         {
                             return [obj2["key1"] compare:obj1["key1"]];
                         }
                         else
                             return result;
                     }];
```

Comment: can you please add the tag of the language that you use!

Comment: sorry. i added the language.

Comment: Wow who downvoted without a valid reason? The downvote fairies are back?

Comment: Do you want to sort one dictionary (the code) or do you want to sort an array of dictionaries (the examples)?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
        NSArray *arrActual = .....;

        NSSortDescriptor * sortKey1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"key1" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor * sortKey2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"key2" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *arrSorted = [arrActual sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDate, sortName]];
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: My data is dictionary and not array.

Answer (score 0):

### **Swift**

This is really where Swift comes in handy. I know this isn't the answer you wanted but this is one powerful functionality of swift arrays that you might want to consider in your upcoming classes should you wish to go with `.swift` over `.m`.

```
let sorted = allSongs.sorted(by: { (firstSong, secondSong) -> Bool in
    if let firstTitle = firstSong.title, let secondTitle = secondSong.title {
        return firstTitle < secondTitle
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
})
```